# Possible causes can be invoking https when the application is not configured for security

Tags: java, web-services

I create web service

```
@WebService(serviceName = "DynamipsService2")
@Stateless()
public class DynamipsService2 {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "StartSession")
    public static String StartSession(@WebParam(name = "key") String key) {
        try {

                return "100-Session started";

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

I want to test but on the page
http://localhost:8080/DynamipsService2/DynamipsService2?Tester crash bug

> Error generating artifacts for the
>   following WSDL
>   http://localhost:8080/DynamipsService2/DynamipsService2?WSDL
>
> Possible causes can be invoking https
>   when the application is not configured
>   for security

I created other Web services in the same assembly and it works.

Comment: 1)Did you run wsgen to produce required artifacts?2)How do you publish the web service?

Comment: @user384706, I do noy understand your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and the reason apeared in the Server's log. I'm useing Glassfish 3.1 with netBeans 7. And the error I got in the Glassfish output was:
INFO: [ERROR] com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not available in the classpath, requires Suns JDK version 5.0 or latter.

I googled a bit and it appeared to be because the glassfish server was working with the openjdk that came with ubuntu. If your problem is the same the solution I found was to remove the openjdk jre, like this:

sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-jre
sudo apt-get autoremove

Hope this is useful.

PS: I assigned /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java in the java tab at the servers configuration wizard in netBeans but don't know if that was part of the solution (I'm afraid to change it back :p)

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced this problem as well. The solution for me was to use my hostname rather than localhost in the URL for the Tester.

So in my case, the following, which is what NetBeans/Glassfish did by default when I clicked Test Web Service in the NetBeans UI, did *not* work:

```
http://localhost:8080/Calculator/Calculator?Tester
```

However, when I paste the following into a browser, it *does* work:

```
http://david-pc:8080/Calculator/Calculator?Tester
```

I couldn't figure out how to change the hostname that NetBeans uses for the built-in Test dialog (nor could I cut+paste the URL from the error dialog). So I had to visually copy the URL from the error message into a browser, replacing the hostname along the way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Glassfish

but it was more compilcated because of the NAT

I have GF in NAT - do  MYDOMAIN and port is redirected to internal machine

the problem in GF is that it tries to connect to itself by the domain name which again redirects to inside network
(the ?wsdl works properly)

I have made temp solution adding to /etc/hosts (127.0.0.1  domainname)
be aware that it's only a temp solution

try to check if you have "localhost"  in your hosts file (in windows c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts )
and ping localhost

I will add GF log - maybe someone in future will search it by google :) :)
moreover I looked GF logs there was something like ->

```
Connection timed out
Failed to read the WSDL document: http://MYDOMAIN:8080/MYSERVICE?WSDL, because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <wsdl:definitions>.
failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):
At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.
Failed to parse the WSDL.
```

Answer (score 0):

Which web server do you use? If you use glassfish you can open server admin page and select `Configurations===>server-config===>Security`

and make Security Manager enabled

Answer (score 0):

Check your domains/{YOUR_DOMAIN}/config/domain.xml

If you setup Glassfish using Eclipse, all will be done for you automatically.

Now I am surprised if I start the domain from the command line, it gave me that error, but starting Glassfish 4 from Eclipse, it is not showing any problem.

Comment: Im in exactly the same boat. What are we checking the domain.xml for?

Answer (score 0):

One cause could be that you don't have correctly configured the environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the correct path) and the JAVA_HOME/bin directory added to global PATH environment variable as well. For some processes the glassfish look for the classpath of the JDK installed.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and it is because you have a static method, I realised after debugging for some while. Just remove static from the method and it should work.

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "StartSession")
public String StartSession(@WebParam(name = "key") String key) {
    try {

            return "100-Session started";

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```